# Cannot test my own REST API from a beta managed package

Tags: apexrest, beta-managed-package, restresource

I developed a REST API for my managed package which works correctly when tested for development in my scratch org but also as a released managed package.

Recently I made minor changes to it - like simply adding the support for an additional query string parameter, nothing extraordinary - and, although it works just fine both on my scratch org and on my packaging org, it doesn't when tested as a beta package. But it's not the change that doesn't work, it's the whole service.

I get a 403 HTTP status code with the payload below whenever I call any of my endpoints:

```
[
  {
    "errorCode": "FORBIDDEN",
    "message": "Request blocked due to package versioning restrictions"
  }
]
```

Comment: Did you change a `global` Apex method signature implementing the REST API?

Comment: I didn't. As I said I really changed a minor thing. At this point I'm not even sure I have ever tested the REST API with my previous beta packages, but it would really be strange. Maybe I should try and test some older beta version for comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what happened. Sadly, if you got to that point there's no solution for it, just a workaround.

You will encounter this error if you first package a global class similar to this.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/my-pretty-path/*')
global with sharing class MyPrettyRestHandler {

    @HttpGet
    global static void doGet() {
        // My pretty logic
    }

}
```

Beautiful, isn't it?
But we all know the rules: once a global class gets packaged and the package is released that class cannot be retired anymore... well, kind of... there's still a painful way you can look into if you really want to ([Revert a managed package to a beta version](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000312548&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)).

However there's literally NO WAY to EVER amend your mistakes if you persevere in the error... enter the `@deprecated` annotation.
In the context of a REST handling class this useful - cough - annotation will help you achieve the perfect path nuking. You just add it like so:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/my-pretty-path/*')
@deprecated
global with sharing class ApplicationRestProvider {
    ...
```

Next you create a new package version (or simply a new version?) and you can high-five yourself. You just made `my-pretty-path` unusable to time indefinite.
The solution for you now is the one of choosing a different path and ask all of your customers using that REST API path to migrate to a different path. Isn't that great? Well, in the end it's me who wanted it...